# How to simplify a pure function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation, pure-function

I am dealing with the vibration of a multi degree of freedom system with driving force, and I need to find the relation between the amplitude and the frequency of the driving force.

I hope to get an accurate solution, So I used `DSolve` to get the analytical solution, then I used `/.` to replace symbols with numeric values. However, I can't simplify the anwser.

Here is a simple example that can explain what I want to do:

How can I simplify

`Function[{t}, t + 1 + 1]`

to

`Function[{t}, t + 2]`

Comment: Not that it's not a good question, but this smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Have you tried `DSolve[expr, y[t], t]` instead of `DSolve[expr, y, t]` to get a non-pure function?  If you're substituting the solution into an expression with derivatives of `y` (or other operators), then you're good, but otherwise it might be simpler to just get the image of `t` under `y` (i.e. `y[t]`) instead of the function itself.  Not trying to dismiss your question, just trying to address the core of your issue as best as possible.

Comment: If you use `DSolve[expr, y[x], t]` instead of `DSolve[expr, y, t]`, you can use the resource function `SolutionRulesToFunctions` to obtain a pure function as follows: `DSolve[expr, y[t], t]//Simplify//SolutionRulesToFunctions`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar, but different, to [@Alan's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274539):

```mathematica
f = Function[{t}, t + 1 + 1];
MapAt[Evaluate, f, {2}]
```

Another one:

```mathematica
f = Function[{t}, t + 1 + 1];
ReplacePart[f, 2 -> f[[2]]]
```

Comment: As written, these leave `f` unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

```
f = Function[{t}, t + 1 + 1]
f[[2]] = f[[2]]
```

Comment: As written, this changes `f`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov My comment was meant to help the OP. Just in case.

Comment: Same here. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

We can also use `Map` (`/@`). Also, if `t` is polluted, we need `Block` etc.:

```
f = Function[{t}, t + 1 + 1];
t = 111;
Block[{t}, Evaluate /@ f]
```

Alternatively:

```
f = Function[{t}, t + 1 + 1];
t = 111;
Block[{t}, Function @@ List @@ f]
```

Or directly use `Block` to disable `Function`:

```
f = Function[{t}, t + 1 + 1];
t = 111;
Block[{t, Function}, f]
```

Just for fun, an unnecessarily complicated but working solution:

```
f = Function[{t}, t + 1 + 1];
t = 111;
Block[{t}, Replace[f, a_ :> RuleCondition@a, {1}]]
```

Comment: Rule for constructing the `Block`: `Verbatim[Function][v_List, body_] :> Block[v, < your favorite fix >]`. If `Function[t,...]`, then give a list of rules covering the cases, I guess, including `Function[Null,...]` (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Using `DSolve[expr, y[t], t]` instead `DSolve[expr, y, t]`:

```
solrules = First @@ DSolve[{y''[x] - x y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y[9] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

[image]

Using `Simplify` and the resource function [SolutionRulesToFunctions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SolutionRulesToFunctions/):

```
solrules //Simplify //SolutionRulesToFunctions
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also similar to other answers (in-place modification):

```
f=Function[{t}, t + 1 + 1]

f[[2]]//=Evaluate;f

(* Function[{t}, 2 + t] *)
```

Alternatively:

```
f//=MapAt[Evaluate,2]
```

There is also `Query`

```
Query[{2->Evaluate}]@f
```

but 'under the hood' this appears to be identical to the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274541/106) given by [Anton Antonov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34008/anton-antonov)

```
Query[{2->Evaluate}]//Normal

(* MapAt[Evaluate, 2] *)
```